# How to use Microsoft add-in in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I have created an add-in for excel. It's working fine for excel sheet. I want to use my add-ins in **google sheet**. I am not getting any idea about how to use add-in into google sheet.

Can anyone tell me that how to use add-in in google sheet. If any documentation is available, then please share it.

Comment: Would you expect your Microsoft excel add-in to work in IBM Lotus notes too? Even though all three products are spreadsheets, and a lot of the functionality and functions in Google Sheets and Microsoft Excel are similar, the addins are not necessarily interchangeable.

Comment: They are all entirely different entities with their own objects model even if they use the same technology stack and programming language - JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

In the current state I think there is no direct way to use an `Excel Add-in` inside Google Sheets.

As far as I know,they are similar to [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) that allows you to extend the capabilities of Google Sheets.

Or open a [new feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113) to include a way to connect an `Add-in` inside Google Sheets.

Answer (score 2):

Google Sheets add-ins and Microsoft Office Add-ins are different entities with entirely different objects models. There is no direct conversion between them. You need to develop separate add-ins.

See [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) for getting started with Google Sheets add-ons.